# Sorting an array with .sort((a,b) => a>b) works. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
[9,2,1,80].sort((a,b) => a>b)
// gives [ 1, 2, 9, 80 ]

[9,2,1,80].sort((a,b) => a<b)
// gives [ 80, 9, 2, 1 ]
```

Why? I have some code that uses the above comparison function. A comparison function for numbers should be something like (a,b) => a-b. Why the above code is correct, if it is?

Comment: It is not correct; it works by coincidence.

Comment: @SLaks a bit of explanation will help mate :)
 in case of numbers i have seen it is being used at many places.

Comment: I don't know where you have seen this, @CodeManiac, but I just tried it on chrome and didn't work...

Comment: @dquijada https://imgur.com/a/mAZiH3c check here it does work. i know how it works. i was just curious to know why it is not correct.

Comment: @CodeManiac: It depends on the JS engine's implementation of `sort()`, and probably also on the exact contents of the array.

Comment: @SLaks in the case of numbers only i have seen it works perfectly fine. but ya as you said with the different content it doesen't.

Comment: I don't get why JavaScript still hasn't added the [`<=>` (spaceship) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/31298778#31298778). It's pretty standard for duck typing languages as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works sometimes - depending on your browser and the input array - because sort expects either a positive number, 0 or a negative number as return value. The expression `a>b`or `a<b` returns a boolean which is converted to 0 or 1. 0 means it's equal, so this is where the specific implementation of the browser -  how it handles those equal values - you are using comes into play.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

You can also tell equal values are not stable by reading the [ECMAScript-spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) (that's what Javascript is based on):

> The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not
>   necessarily remain in their original order). 
>   [...]
>   If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the sort order is implementation-defined.

Comment: I added a link to the ECMAScript-spec and a quotation about elements that are equal being unstable.

Comment: The relevant part here is probably "If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the sort order is implementation-defined." I changed your link to point directly at the definition of `Array.prototype.sort`

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, I added it to my answer.

Comment: I still wouldn't rely on an arbitrarily defined sorting function, it's better to use functions which are specified to work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` returns only 0 (equal) or 1 (greater), while sort compare function must return negative, zero or positive.that why the > or <  work for some value

Comment: It would be more accurate to say the comparison returns boolean true or false which get implicitly converted to 1 or 0 respectively.