# simplification of imbricated javascript for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, recursion

I have a several levels deep javscript object. All levels are objects except the final levels which are arrays I need to sort.

My code so far looks like this :

```js
for (let group in objRes) {
    if (objRes.hasOwnProperty(group)) {
        for (let type in objRes[group]) {
            if (objRes[group].hasOwnProperty(type)) {
                for (let name in objRes[group][type]) {
                    if (objRes[group][type].hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        for (let tenor in objRes[group][type][name]) {
                            if (objRes[group][type][name].hasOwnProperty(tenor)) {
                                objRes[group][type][name][tenor] = objRes[group][type][name][tenor].sort((x,y)=>x.date>y.date);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The levels (`group`,`type`,`name`,`tenor`) are all strings and the last level array members look like : `{date:'2019-12-25',value:35}`

So `objRes` looks like

```js
{
group1:
    {type1:
        {name1:
            {tenor1:[{date:'2019-12-25',value:35},...],
         name2 :{...}
         }
    },
    {type2 :{...}},
group2:{...}
}
```

Is there a clever way to simplify this ?

You can assume that the number of levels is known or not.

Comment: Please update your question with a representative example of the contents of `objRes`.

Comment: If the number of levels is arbitrary, what condition tells you to stop and do the `sort`? What is it about the objects at that level?

Comment: You can probably write a recursive function to check if it has lower levels

Comment: The update doesn't provide a representative example of the contents of `objRes`, it's not at all clear where the ends of the objects are (your curly braces are unmatched). If you're not willing to put in effort on your question to ensure it's clear, with useful sample data, etc., why should people put in effort answering it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive function for this. It's hard to give an exact example based on the information in the question, but for instance:

```
function process(obj) {
    // Loop through the values of the own properties of the object
    for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
        // Is this the termination condition?
        if (Array.isArray(value)) { // <== A guess at the condition, adjust as needed
            // We've reached the bottom
            value.sort((x, y) => x.date.localeCompare(y.date)); // <== Note correction, you can't just return the result of `>`
        } else {
            // Not the termination, recurse
            process(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example using a guess at your data:

```js
function process(obj) {
    // Loop through the values of the own properties of the object
    for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
        // Is this the termination condition?
        if (Array.isArray(value)) { // <== A guess at the condition, adjust as needed
            // We've reached the bottom
            value.sort((x, y) => x.date.localeCompare(y.date)); // <== Note correction, you can't just return the result of `>`
        } else {
            // Not the termination, recurse
            process(value);
        }
    }
}

const objRes = {
    group1: {
        type1: {
            name1: {
                tenor1: [
                    {date: '2019-12-23', value: 35},
                    {date: '2019-12-25', value: 32},
                    {date: '2019-12-24', value: 30},
                ]
            },
            name2 :[]
        },
        type2: {}
    },
    group2: {}
};
process(objRes);
console.log(JSON.stringify(objRes, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Some notes on that:

1. You can avoid the `for-in`/`hasOwnProperty` combination by using `Object.values`.
2. You can loop through those values with `for-of`.
3. There has to be *some* termination condition telling the function when it's reached "the bottom." In that example I've used `Array.isArray` because you're sorting at the final level.
4. `Array.prototype.sort` modifies the array directly, you don't need to use its return value.
5. The function you pass to `sort` must return a negative number, 0, or a positive number, not a boolean (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison)). Since your `date` values appear to be strings in `yyyy-MM-dd` form, you can use `localeCompare` to do that (since it happens that in that format, a lexicographic comparison is also a date comparison).

Answer (score 0):

This alternate to the answer from T.J. Crowder takes several of the decision points mentioned there and makes them explicit function calls.

```js
const process = (test, transform, data) =>
  typeof data == "object"
    ? ( Array .isArray (data)
       ? (xs) => xs .map (([_, x]) => x)
       : Object .fromEntries
      ) ( Object .entries (data) .map (([k, v]) => 
        [k, test (k, v) ? transform (v) : process (test, transform, v)]
      ))
    : data
```

It accepts two functions as well as your data object.  The first one is to test whether you've hit a nested value you want to massage.  So we could imagine something like `(k, v) => k .startsWith ('tenor')` or `(k, v) => Array .isArray (v)`.  The second function accepts the value at that entry and returns an updated value, perhaps `(v) => v . sort((a, b) => a .date .localeCompare (b .date))`.

(**Note**: Your sort call is problematic.  Don't use `.sort ((a, b) => a < b)`, which returns a boolean that is then coerced into a `0` or a `1`, whereas a proper comparator should return `-1` when `a < b`.  If you can compare with `<`, then this should always work `(a, b) =>  a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0`.  I don't know if there's a more complete SO question on this than [Sorting an array with .sort((a,b) => a>b) works. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53837990/).)

You can see it in action in this snippet:

```js
const process = (test, transform, data) =>
  typeof data == "object"
    ? ( Array .isArray (data)
        ? (xs) => xs .map (([_, x]) => x)
        : Object .fromEntries
      ) ( Object .entries (data) .map (([k, v]) => 
        [k, test (k, v) ? transform (v) : process (test, transform, v)]
      ))
    : data    

const dateSort = (xs) => xs .slice (0) .sort ((a, b) => a .date .localeCompare (b .date))

const objRes = {
    group1: {
        type1: {
            name1: {
                tenor1: [
                    {date: '2019-12-23', value: 35},
                    {date: '2019-12-25', value: 32},
                    {date: '2019-12-24', value: 30},
                ]
            },
            name2: []
        },
        type2: {}
    },
    group2: {
        type3: [
            {date: '2020-01-03', value: 42},
            {date: '2019-01-01', value: 43},
            {date: '2019-01-02', value: 44},
        ]
    }
};

// This one only sorts the first group of dates
console .log (
  process (
    (k, v) => k .startsWith ('tenor'),
    dateSort,
    objRes
  )
)

// This one sorts both groups
console .log (
  process (
    (k, v) => Array .isArray (v),
    dateSort,
    objRes
  )
)
```

The code is a bit dense.  The outermost condition applies our processing only if the data is an object, returning it intact if not, and doing the following processing if it is:

We first use `Object.entries` to turn our object into name-value pairs, then map over that object by testing each pair to see whether we've hit something we should transform and returning either the transformed value or the result of recursing on the value.

Perhaps the trickiest bit is this:

```
      ( Array .isArray (data)
        ? (xs) => xs .map (([_, x]) => x)
        : Object .fromEntries
      )
```

Here we just choose a function to apply to the converted pairs to turn it back into a whole.  If it's an array, we skip the keys and return an array of the values.  If it's not, we use `Object.fromEntries` to create an object of them.  If [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is [not available in your environment](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-entries), it's easy to shim.