# Why Firefox 105.0 (64 bits) and MS Edge Version 105.0.1343.42 (Version officielle) (64 bits) sorts differently?

Tags: sorting, logging, firefox, console, microsoft-edge

Why this sort task does not perform in MS Edge, but it acts very well in the firefox ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
  const arr = ["stella","gamma","area","benzyl","xtra"];
  console.log(arr.sort((x,y)=>x>y));
  console.log(arr.sort((x,y)=>x-y));

  // MS Edge Version 105.0.1343.42 (Version officielle) (64 bits) :
  // (5) ['stella', 'gamma', 'area', 'benzyl', 'xtra']
  // (5) ['stella', 'gamma', 'area', 'benzyl', 'xtra']

  // Firefox 105.0 (64 bits) :
  // Array(5) [ "area", "benzyl", "gamma", "stella", "xtra" ]
  // Array(5) [ "area", "benzyl", "gamma", "stella", "xtra" ]
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Doct Jean-Dadet Luyalu. May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, chromium browsers use a different sort function (**QuickSort**) from Firefox (**MergeSort**), which leads to discrepancies in results.

Normally, in order to sort **strings**, we just use `array.sort()`, and it works fine on both Edge and Firefox.

As for `array.sort((x,y)=>x>y)`, normally we don't write such code, but we can expect that Firefox has modified its source code to make it work. For more information, you can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837990/sorting-an-array-with-sorta-b-ab-works-why).

As for `array.sort((x,y)=>x-y)`, it does not work in both browsers for sorting **strings**. In this case, it displays the well sorted array just because the `array.sort((x,y)=>x>y)` has already rearranged the original array. It is used for **number** sorting.

Comment: Does stuff at ms-edge know about their weakness and discrepancy to normalize behaviour of all the browsers ?

Comment: In fact, it's a feature shared by all chromium browsers, including Edge, Chrome and Opera. It is more of a difference than weakness. They know the differences for sure.